# Como inicio la pagina?

Tags: reactjs, terminal

estoy utilizando React Js y necesito iniciar mi pagina en google pero al poner el codigo para iniciarlo, no funciona. Me saltan los siguientes errores. ¿Que codigo o cual es el error? ¿Debo agregar algo de mas? [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Imagino descargaste el código de algun lugar, ya que hasta donde veo, no haz instalado las dependencias del proyecto. De igual manera te recomiendo seas más especifico con tu pregunta y no uses imagines, para presentar código. Edita tu pregunta, se especifico y detallado.